# Getting values depending on the dropdown

Tags: php, sql, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list for items. What I want to do is get the item quantity, remaining quantity and dispatched item values which depends on the value in the drop down.

I have this code :

```
<form method="post" action="restore_stocks.php">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Item Name:</td>
<td><select name="itemname">
<?php
  $item="SELECT item_name FROM stocks";
  $itemresult = @mysql_query($item)or die ("Error in query: $query. " .                                     mysql_error());
  while($row=@mysql_fetch_array($itemresult)){
echo "<OPTION VALUE=".$row['item_name'].">".$row['item_name']."</option>";
}
?>
</select></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Item Quantity:</td>
<td><?php 
$row = mysql_fetch_object($itemresult);

echo $row->item_quantity; ?></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Remaining Quantity:</td>
<td><?php echo $row->rem_quantity; ?></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Stocks Dispatched:</td>
<td><?php echo $row->stocks_dispatched; ?></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Add Stocks:</td>
<td><input name="addstocks" type="text" size="25" maxlength="25" /></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Restore" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I really don't know how to start the code because i'm new to this approach. If you can help me it's much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works: The jist is that the page uses ajax to call a script, which will deliver XML of the values you need, and will then populate those fields accordingly. :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
function updateFields(itemname){
    var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    var xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
    var iQdata=xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("ITEMQUANTITY");
    var rQdata=xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("REMAININGQUANTITY");
    var sDdata=xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("STOCKSDISPATCHED");
    var iQ=iQdata[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    var rQ=rQdata[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    var sD=sDdata[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    document.getElementById("itemQuantity").innerHTML=iQ;
    document.getElementById("remainingQuantity").innerHTML=rQ;
    document.getElementById("stocksDispatched").innerHTML=sD;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","quantity_script.php?itemname="+itemname,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>

<form method="post" action="restore_stocks.php">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Item Name:</td>
<td><select name="itemname" onchange="updateFields(this.value)">
<?php
  $item="SELECT item_name FROM stocks";
  $itemresult = @mysql_query($item)or die ("Error in query: $query. " .mysql_error());
  while($row=@mysql_fetch_array($itemresult)){
echo "<OPTION VALUE=".$row['item_name'].">".$row['item_name']."</option>";
}
?>
</select></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Item Quantity:</td>
<td><div id="itemQuantity"></div></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Remaining Quantity:</td>
<td><div id="remainingQuantity"></div></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Stocks Dispatched:</td>
<td><div id="stocksDispatched"></div></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Add Stocks:</td>
<td><input name="addstocks" type="text" size="25" maxlength="25" /></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Restore" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And then you'd also make a script on your site "quantity_script.php" that would be something like the following:

```
<?php
//include your DB connection info
$itemname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["itemname"]);
$item="SELECT ".$itemname." FROM stocks";
$itemresult = mysql_query($item);
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($itemresult);
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo "<ROOT>";
echo "<ITEMQUANTITY>".$row["item_quantity"]."</ITEMQUANTITY>";
echo "<REMAININGQUANTITY>".$row["rem_quantity"]."</REMAININGQUANTITY>";
echo "<STOCKSDISPATCHED>".$row["stocks_dispatched"]."</STOCKSDISPATCHED>";
echo "</ROOT>";
?>
```

Comment: @renz, what? You are not familiar with functions?

Comment: @renz: Then you have a lot of reading to do! This is not the only way to do it, but you should spend some time trying to find out why this works. Also, you should accept the answer.